# Using readtable on .csv with junk text after last cell

Tags: matlab

I'm using `readtable` to read a `.csv` which contains a line of gunk at the bottom:

```
ColA, ColB, ColC,
42  , foo , 1.1
666 , bar , 2.2
SomeGunk, 101
```

*(yup, first line has a trailing `,`, but that doesn't seem to be an issue)*

... which upsets `readtable`:

```
>> readtable(file)
Error using readtable (line 197)
Reading failed at line 4. All lines of a text file must
    have the same number of delimiters. Line 4 has 2 delimiters,
    while preceding lines have 3.

Note: readtable detected the following parameters:
'Delimiter', ',', 'HeaderLines', 1, 'ReadVariableNames', false, 'Format', 
    '%f%q%q%q%q%f%f%f%D%D%q%q%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f'
```

What can I do?

Is there anything short of reading the file and writing it back out again minus the last line? This seems really clumsy. And if I must do this, what's the cleanest way?

Comment: Please add part of your relevant code and an example of the file contents.

Comment: Is [`csvread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017a/matlab/ref/csvread.html) an option? You could convert the data to a table afterwards...

Comment: How does the `SomeGunk` look? Maybe you can define that as a comment, e.g. in your example, add `'CommentStyle', 'SomeGunk'` to the `readtable` call.

Comment: @hbaderts, That last line is of the form `TDD,332351.8,N,825,Sortino,1.902`. Cells 1,3,5 will always be `"TDD"`, `"N"`, `"Sortino"`.

Comment: @souty, I looked up `csvread`, apparently it only works for numeric data. And my data is a mix.

Comment: Then defining `"TDD"` as a comment (i.e. a line starting with that is ignored) would work, or can `"TDD"` also appear in lines that you need?

Answer (score 3):

The [`readtable`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) function lets you manually define a comment symbol. From the documentation:

> For example, specify a character such as `'%'` to ignore text following the symbol on the same line. Specify a cell array of two character vectors, such as `{'/*', '*/'}`, to ignore any text between those sequences.

That means, you can define `'someGunk'` to be the comment symbol, i.e. any line starting with `'someGunk'` will be ignored:

```
>> readtable('gunk.csv', 'Delimiter', ',', 'CommentStyle', 'SomeGunk')
ans =

  2×3 table

    Var1     Var2     Var3
    ____    ______    ____

     42     'foo '    1.1 
    666     'bar '    2.2
```

This works only under the conditions that 1) the rubbish lines will *always* start with `'SomeGunk'`, 2) `'SomeGunk'` does not appear anywhere else in the file, and 3) you don't need any other comment symbols.